# Identify selected date range in react-date-range

Tags: reactjs, date-range

I am using react-date-range plugin to select a date range.

```
import { DateRangePicker} from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';
```

[image]

Following function is used to handle the date range when a range is selected

```
    function handleSelect() {
            
    }
```

I have added the DateRangePicker like this

```
const selectionRange = {
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    key: 'selection',
}

<div>
    <DateRangePicker
    ranges={[selectionRange]}
    onChange={handleSelect}/>
</div>
```

I want to make some operations on the selected date range in side the handleChange function. But I cannot find how to identify which date range is selected and the respective start and end dates.

In documentation onChange callback is described as
[image]

But I cannot understand how to get these startDate and endDate parameters.
Can someone help me to get this values.

Documentation: https://openbase.io/js/react-date-range/documentation

Comment: You will get the selected date range in its handler function `handleSelect(date){
    console.log(date); // native Date object
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range#daterangepicker--daterange) the `onChange` callback receives the `ranges` as an argument:

```
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  handleSelect(ranges){
    console.log(ranges);
    // {
    //   selection: {
    //     startDate: [native Date Object],
    //     endDate: [native Date Object],
    //   }
    // }
  }
  render(){
    const selectionRange = {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    }
    return (
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        onChange={this.handleSelect}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

It should be an object that has a key `selection` which is itself an object that contains the `startDate` and `endDate`.

Comment: How do you open the DateRange just after clicking on the date input? I mean, I don't want to keep it open all the time.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
const onChange = (item) => {
    if (item.selection.endDate !== item.selection.startDate) {
        console.log(item);
        setIsPopoverOpen(false);
    }
    setRange([item.selection]);
}
```